# CSS path problem in the EE3 installation script and in the Admin Panel

Tags: css, path, install, admin.php

I installed EE 3.5.4 on a local server (Wamp 3.0.6 - Windows 10), during the installation script execution, the CSS files were not taken into account, then the  installation display was summary. The installation worked well.

When I entered in the admin page, the same problem occurred:  the CSS files were not taken into account, there was only text. Then I looked at the path of the CSS file and it had admin.php in the path

> href="http://localsite/**admin.php**/themes/ee/cp/css/common.min.css

**The httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

the **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localsite
    DocumentRoot "d:/drive/sites/www/localsite"
    <Directory  "d:/drive/sites/www/localsite/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside the Windows **hosts file**:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1   localsite
::1 localsite
```

This problem never happened to me before. I managed to solve the problem

In the **config.php** file:

```
system/user/config/config.php
```

**I added:**

```
$config['theme_folder_url'] = 'http://localsite/themes/';
```

And now the CSS path is right (**no more admin.php**):

```
href="http://localsite/themes/ee/cp/css/common.min.css
```

Really I do not understand this problem, is it possible to remove **admin.php** in the CSS path without modifying the **config.php** file?

PS : i tried to install EE2, there was a problem with the images path.

Comment: I've never seen this before - it seems that somehow during the installation, admin.php was added to the site URL. This value doesn't have to be changed via config.php - it can also be changed in the URL and path settings in the control panel. But it is fixed now yes?

Comment: Hi Derek, me too I've never seen this before. I tried many times, each time the installation script was without CSS, the admin panel too. Yes the config.php modification has solved the problem. I wrote this post in case an other person encounter the same problem. I will investigate the Wamp setting.

Comment: It could give an headache for someone who doesn't know how to set config.php and Wamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

In the **httpd.conf** (Windows 10, Wampserver 3.0.6 64 Bit)

**I replaced:**

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www" 
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
```

**to the name of my sites root:**

```
DocumentRoot "D:/drive/sites/www"
<Directory "D:/drive/sites/www/">
```

I removed:

```
$config['theme_folder_url'] = 'http://localsite/themes/';
```

In the **config.php** file:

```
system/user/config/config.php
```

And now, **no more problems with the CSS path**, not need anymore to change this value via config.php. It was a Wamp (3.0.6) , Apache (2.4.23) config setting.

**The Answers from those questions helped me to solve this problem:**

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43522/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver